# RxJs custom operator with function as input

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Im trying to create to create a custom rxjs operator. I've already created a few custom operator (e.g. MonoTypeOperatorFunction or just regular Observable, that can take in input as a string, number etc.) and they work fine. My problem is that i want to create an operator that takes in a anonymous function. Like x => x.prop or a predicate.

In this example i want to create an operator that can flatten the elements in an object.

```
interface B {
  bid: number;
}

interface A {
  aid: number;
  bs: B[];
}

const b1: B = { bid: 1 };
const b2: B = { bid: 2 };

const a1: A = { aid: 1, bs: [b1, b2] };

const a1$ = of(a1);

// I want to combine map and concatMap into a single operator
const result = a1$.pipe(
  map(x => x.bs),
  concatMap(x => x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
// OUTPUT: {bid:1}, {bid:2}

// what i want
// a1$.pipe(many(x => x.bs))

// How i tried to create an operator
// function many<T>(predicate: (input: T) => boolean) {
//   return function<T1>(source: Observable<T1>) {
//     return source.pipe(map(predicate),concatMap(x => x));
//   };
// }
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the snippet? It looks good to me, but I might be missing something

Comment: @AndreiGătej I want to combine map and concatMap into a single operator. In my example, i call it many. I will like to have a generic implementation that works for all objects that have a list property if that makes sense

Comment: If I uncomment the code it gives me this; Argument of type '(input: any) => T' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<any>'.(2345)

Comment: Could you reproduce the error in a StackBlitz app or something similar? It would be easier to find a solution that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already an operator that combines map and concatMap into a single operator, it's called `concatMap`.

`pipe(map(somefunc), concatMap(x => x))` is always the same as `concatMap(somefunc)`. Which explains why it's called concat**Map** ;)

---

Your function:

The function you wrote can be rewritten as follows:

```js
function many<T>(predicate: (input: T) => boolean) {
  return pipe(map(predicate),concatMap(x => x));
}
```

which is the same as

```js
function many<T>(predicate: (input: T) => boolean) {
  return concatMap(predicate);
}
```

When you look at this, you should be able to see that you're transforming your stream of type `T` into a stream of type `boolean`. `concatMap` can't subscribe to a boolean. You'll need a function of type `(input: T) => Observable<R>`. Which is the same type signature that `concatMap` already takes.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you! But should it not be function many<T>(predicate: (input: T) => T[]) ?

Comment: Most high-order operators (concatMap, mergeMap, switchMap, defer, concatAll, mergeAll, etc) will subscribe to an array by turning it into a stream for you. So yes, `someFunction: (input: T) => R[]` will work! :)